# I have am encountering error 'rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Reality' while trying to seed in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Why is Heroku ignoring my Reality 
It doesnt recognize Reality! 
perhaps also, an existential question, but i simply want to seed my heroku database :(

I have searched everywhere for possible answers. I can create reality objects in heroku manually, but *not* using the seeds.rb file. Category and User seeding working fine!

My exact error

```
D, [2017-05-21T21:18:48.820957 #4] DEBUG -- :   
Category Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
D, [2017-05-21T21:18:48.826565 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.1ms)
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Reality
/app/db/seeds.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties
5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord
5.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord
5.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in `block (2
levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in
`block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in`each'/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:i
`execute'/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in
`mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in
`invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in
`invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake
12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top
(required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in
`invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in
`block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler
1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in
`<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
➜  reality-checker git:(master) ✗
```

My Models

reality.rb

```
class Reality < ApplicationRecord
 validates :user, presence: true
 validates :category, presence: true

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :category
 has_many :favorites
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :realities
   has_many :favorites
   has_many :timers
   validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
 include PgSearch

 validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
 validates :description, presence: true

 pg_search_scope :search_category_only, against: [:title, :description]
 scope :search, ->(query) { search_category_only(query) if query.present? }

 has_many :realities
 has_many :timers

end
```

And last of all, the Gemfile!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cowsay'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'coveralls', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'valid_attribute'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

 group :test do
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My seeds.rb file. Reality in line 7 breaks in heroku

```
Category.destroy_all
User.destroy_all
Reality.destroy_all
##   movies = Movie.create!([{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'Lord of 
the Rings' }])
#   Character.create!(name: 'Luke', movie: movies.first)

if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
  CategorySeeder.seed!
end
reality = Reality.all
category = Category.all
user1 = User.create!(email: 'philipormorgan@gmail.com', username: 
'Philip', password: '123456', admin: true)

philosophy = category[0]
love = category[1]
wisdom = category[2]
work = category[3]
traveling = category[4]
tv = category[5]
food = category[6]
anecdotes = category[7]
literature = category[8]
history = category[9]
developing = category[10]
music = category[11]
politics = category[12]
random = category[13]
Reality.create!(check: 'My philosophy is: if you can not have fun,
there is no sense in doing it-Paul Walker', user: user1, category: 
philosophy )

Reality.create!(check: 'Philosophy begins in wonder-Plato', user: 
user1, category: philosophy )
Reality.create!(check: 'Enjoy life, this is not a rehearsal.', user:
user1, category: philosophy )
Reality.create!(check: 'Every day may not be good, but there is
something good in every day.', user: user1, category: philosophy )
Reality.create!(check: 'Write a wise saying and your name will live
forever-anonymous', user: user1, category: philosophy )
Reality.create!(check: 'He who dies with the most toys is, nonetheless,
still dead.-anonymous', user: user1, category: philosophy )
Reality.create!(check: 'Life is about making dreams come true', user: user1, category: philosophy )
```

...ect

**EDIT**

I have recreated models
I have restarted the heroku db multiple times

```
class CategorySeeder
CATEGORIES = [
{
  title: "Philosophy",
  description: "The world's greatest unanswered questions"
}, {
  title: "Love",
  description: "Your perception on love"
}, {
  title: "Wisdom",
  description: "Wise words from wise people"
}, {
  title: "Work/School",
  description: "Don't be too negative on this one ;)"
}, {
  title: "Traveling",
  description: "Your favorite Travel spots, and stories from traveling"
}, {
  title: "TV entertainment",
  description: "Movies, shows, media, and other forms of entertainment"
}, {
  title: "Food/Cooking",
  description: "Stories about cooking, your favorite recipes, and more"
}, {
  title: "Anecdotes",
  description: "Stories from your life"
}, {
  title: "Literature",
  description: "Favorite/least favorite books, quotes from books, and quotes form authors"
}, {
  title: "History",
  description: "Your favorite, or most important historical events and quotes"
}, {
  title: "Web Developing",
  description: "Interesting facts and stories about developer scene"
}, {
  title: "Music",
  description: "Favorite current, or upcoming artists songs and quotes"
}, {
  title: "Politics",
  description: "Your opinions on the current political environment (this could get ugly)"
}, {
  title: "Random",
  description: "The title speaks for itself! This could be anything"
}
].freeze

def self.seed!
  CATEGORIES.each do |category_params|
    title = category_params[:title]
    category = Category.find_or_initialize_by(title: title)
    category.assign_attributes(category_params)
    category.save!
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: What does `rails db:migrate:status` print?

Comment: Do you have a second reality.rb file anywhere in the app? Maybe one of your gems does?

Comment: database: Reality-Checker_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20170429161956  Devise create users
   up     20170430201841  Create categories
   up     20170502144325  Create realities
   up     20170508193708  Devise create views
   up     20170509182739  Create delayed jobs
   up     20170509190704  Create timers
   up     20170511175223  Create favorites

Comment: i have checked a few hundred times i dont see any duplicate files and i have not seen reality as a reserved word or gem anywhere!
Also this all works in development.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma

Comment: && @Bartosz. forgot to tag

Comment: Do you get any error if you run `Reality.all` in heroku console?

Comment: @Gerry
Running rails console on ⬢ secure-crag-38014... up, run.9235 (Free)
Loading production environment (Rails 5.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> Reality.all
D, [2017-05-22T04:11:38.069966 #4] DEBUG -- :   Reality Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "realities".* FROM "realities"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
That command actually works. it seems its only in my seeds file it is not recgonized. :(

Comment: What is `CategorySeeder.seed!` for? Can you share that code too?

Comment: @Gerry i just updated my post to include the category seeder. It was the way i originally seeded my db, i have a seeder file that organizes seeds but i stopped because I wasn't sure how to associate Reality as neatly. I opted to throw the Realities in my seeds file